# Generating a PHP file from an application using a WordPress template

Tags: php, wordpress

I am developing an application that installs a copy of WordPress locally. In the application I'm developing I want it to replace the `database_name_here` in the `wp-config-sample.php`, so that it has the correct name as well as the username and password. And when I copy the file to `wp-config.php` the info is correct.

I have used

```
$test = htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents($wp_config_sample_file))
```

To get the contents of the `wp-config-sample.php` file and tried to use

```
$var = array(
  'database_name_here' => 'fred',
  );

$wp_config = strstr($test, $var);
```

and no changes are made. I have also tried `str_replace` which will work but it seems to ignore any matches that appear between the `<?php ?>` tags.

So in summary, I'm trying to create a `wp-config.php` file from `wp-config-sample.php` programatically that contains the hostname, username and password instead of me going into the file structure and editing the file directly before I can start developing. My application is to manage multiple WordPress installations locally for development purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this example](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-str-replace-associative-array/) on how to replace items on a string based on an associative array, it's quite simple:

```
<?php
$string = htmlspecialchars( file_get_contents( 'wp-config-sample.php' ) );

$replacements = array(
    'database_name_here' => 'dbname',
    'username_here'      => 'username',
    'password_here'      => 'password'
);

$wp_config = str_replace( array_keys( $replacements ), $replacements, $string );

printf( '<pre><code>%s</code></pre>', print_r( $wp_config, true ) );
```

<sub>Maybe of interest: [How to Create a Custom WordPress Install Package?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/77597/how-to-create-a-custom-wordpress-install-package/77641#77641)</sub>